# Show only Active Business Accounts on Selector

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I want to only show business accounts in the business account selector on the 'Sales Quotes' screen whose status are not 'Inactive'. I have been trying to use the Selector attribute to filter for all business accounts but the inactive ones using the following code:

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]

    [PXSelector(typeof(Select<BAccount, Where<BAccount.status, NotEqual<inactive>>>))]
    public int? BAccountID { get; set; }


    public const string Inactive = "I";
    public class inactive : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Constant<inactive>
    {
        public inactive() : base(Inactive) {; }
    }
```

But I keep on getting this error:
[image: A foreign key reference cannot be created from the type...]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

BAccountID field in the Quote DAC is decorated with an attribute named CustomerAndProspect.  So what I did is copied that attribute declaration, added a Where clause to exclude the inactive records....like this.

```
public class CustomBAccountSelector
{
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.prospectType>,
                Or<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.customerType>,
                Or<BAccountR.type, Equal<BAccountType.combinedType>,
                And<Where<BAccountR.status,NotEqual<BAccountR.status.inactive>>>>>>), Messages.BAccountIsType, typeof(BAccountR.type))]
    public class CustomerAndProspectAttributeExtension : BAccountAttribute
    {
        public CustomerAndProspectAttributeExtension()
            : base()
        {
            this.Filterable = true;
            this.DisplayName = "Customer";
        }
    }
}
```

Next I override the BaccountID declaration with the new attribute.

```
      #region BAccountID  
    [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
    [CustomerAndProspectAttributeExtension(DisplayName = "Business Account", BqlField = typeof(Standalone.CROpportunityRevision.bAccountID), Enabled = false)]
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<CROpportunity.bAccountID, Where<CROpportunity.opportunityID, Equal<Current<CRQuote.opportunityID>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but what did work in the end was adding a restrictor to a cache attached event handler for the field.